Specifying interactions, quadratics and ratios in regression model
I would like to model a linear regression with the dependent continuous variable y and the independent continuous variables x and z:
The interaction of x and z is expected to increase y, but y is expected to decrease again if the value of x is either too low or too high relative to the value of z.
I have considered the following approaches:

y = x + z + xz + (xz)^2
This specification does not take into account that y is likely to decrease if the value of x is either too low or too high in relation to the value of z

y = x + z + x*z + x/z + (x/z)^2
This specification appears to be overspecified and difficult to interpret.


Do you have any suggestions how to model this relationship?

You could use splines of x, z, and their interaction.
